# Where to upload app-ads.txt file for iOS app?

Tags: ios, admob, ads, adsense, iab

My iOS app support URL is no more active. So where I can add `app-ads.txt` file?

Any alternative way to manage this `IAB` policy?

Comment: How did you solved?

Comment: @MichelMarqués I uploaded app-ads.txt file into the root directory of the website which we set as a Marketing URL on iTunes connect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any website so after some research, I've solved following this steps: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/app-ads#firebase Firebase allows you create and host website and app-ads. It's easy!